# git-bash.exe in context menu with custom command

Tags: command-line, bash, git, context-menu

I would like to get a context menu entry like `Git Bash here`, with an additional command processed.

The command I want to call is `git clean -xdf --dry-run`

What I have done so far is to add an extra entry in the regedit with the suffix `-c <command>`, but it is not working. The windows pops up and closes immediately.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following command works, but it does not use the `git bash`. it uses the internal command prompt:

`cmd.exe /C "git clean -xdf --dry-run -i"`